# Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable line not defined

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

What i am doing is as below. 1st apoc.do.when happily consumes line variable, but when the cypher reach (WITH value.r AS r, line ) I got breaking code with error Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable line not defined

The Cypher execution fails with this error Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable line not defined (line 12, column 20 (offset: 469)) "WITH value.r AS r, line "                                                                                 ^

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///the-file-name.csv" as 
line FIELDTERMINATOR ','  
with line as line
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Region) 
WHERE  n.region contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND n.identifier= line.CODE_TER 
with n
CALL apoc.do.when(
   n IS NULL,
  'MERGE (r:Region{region: line.TERRITOIRE}) ON CREATE SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET r.id = toString(id(r)) RETURN r',
  'RETURN n AS r',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.r AS r, line 
SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER
SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE
SET r.region=line.TERRITOIRE
WITH r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City) where ci.cityName contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND ci.regionIdentifier= line.CODE_TER
CALL apoc.do.when(
   ci IS NULL,
  'MERGE (c:City {cityName:line.BRICK}) ON CREATE SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.description=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET c.id = toString(id(c)) RETURN c',
  'RETURN ci AS c',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.c AS c,line,r
SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE
SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER
SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK
SET c.description=line.BRICK
SET c.cityName=line.BRICK  
WITH c,r,line
MATCH (c {identifier:line.CODE_BRICK}),(r {identifier:line.CODE_TER})
MERGE (c)-[:IS_A_City_BELONGING_TO]->(r)
WITH c,r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (sec:Sector) 
WHERE  sec.description contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND sec.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
CALL apoc.do.when(
   sec IS NULL,
  'MERGE (s:Sector {sectorName:line.SOUSBRICK}) ON CREATE SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK ON CREATE SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET s.city=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.id = toString(id(s)) RETURN s',
  'RETURN sec AS s',
  {}) YIELD value
WITH value.s AS s,line,c,r
SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK 
SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE 
SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
SET s.city=line.BRICK 
SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.sectorName = line.SOUSBRICK   
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(r{identifier:line.CODE_TER}) 
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_REGION]->(r) 
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(c{identifier:line.CODE_BRICK})
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_CITY]->(c)
```

**the-file-name.csv is on the previous question** [How to make the Cypher request to handle those both cases without duplicating Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497811/how-to-make-the-cypher-request-to-handle-those-both-cases-without-duplicating-no)

Here I put The update from the advice of cybersam and Dave Thank you very much for you both.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///the-file-name.csv" as line 
FIELDTERMINATOR ','  
with line as line
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Region) 
WHERE  n.region contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND n.identifier= line.CODE_TER 
WITH n, line
CALL apoc.do.when(
   n IS NULL,
  'MERGE (r:Region{region: line.TERRITOIRE}) ON CREATE SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET r.id = toString(id(r)) RETURN r',
  'RETURN n AS r',
  {n: n, line: line}) YIELD value
WITH value.r AS r, line 
SET r.identifier=line.CODE_TER
SET r.description=line.TERRITOIRE
SET r.region=line.TERRITOIRE
WITH r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (ci:City) where ci.cityName contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND ci.regionIdentifier= line.CODE_TER
CALL apoc.do.when(
   ci IS NULL,
  'MERGE (c:City {cityName:line.BRICK}) ON CREATE SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET c.description=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET c.id = toString(id(c)) RETURN c',
  'RETURN ci AS c',
  {ci: ci, line: line}) YIELD value
WITH value.c AS c,line,r
SET c.identifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET c.region=line.TERRITOIRE
SET c.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER
SET c.zip=line.CODE_BRICK
SET c.description=line.BRICK
SET c.cityName=line.BRICK  
WITH c,r,line
MATCH (c {identifier:line.CODE_BRICK}),(r {identifier:line.CODE_TER})
MERGE (c)-[:IS_A_City_BELONGING_TO]->(r)
WITH c,r,line
OPTIONAL MATCH (sec:Sector) 
WHERE  sec.description contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND sec.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
CALL apoc.do.when(
   sec IS NULL,
  'MERGE (s:Sector {sectorName:line.SOUSBRICK}) ON CREATE SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK ON CREATE SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE ON CREATE SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER ON CREATE SET s.city=line.BRICK ON CREATE SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK ON CREATE SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK ON CREATE SET s.id = toString(id(s)) RETURN s',
  'RETURN sec AS s',
  {sec: sec, line: line}) YIELD value
WITH value.s AS s,line,c,r
SET s.identifier=line.CODE_SBRICK 
SET s.region=line.TERRITOIRE 
SET s.regionIdentifier=line.CODE_TER 
SET s.city=line.BRICK 
SET s.cityIdentifier=line.CODE_BRICK 
SET s.description=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.zip=line.SOUSBRICK 
SET s.sectorName = line.SOUSBRICK   
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(r{identifier:line.CODE_TER}) 
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_REGION]->(r) 
WITH s,c,r,line
MATCH (s {identifier:line.CODE_SBRICK}),(c{identifier:line.CODE_BRICK})
MERGE (s)-[:IS_A_SECTOR_BELONGING_TO_THAT_CITY]->(c)
```

The result :

**Set 28271 properties, created 3400 relationships, completed after 34985 ms.**

It took nearby 35 sec to load csv to neo4j db.
please is it right perfect in performance view ?

for a csv file containing 1665 csv lines
each line contains 6 fields : two first fields for (Region) the third and fourth (City) and the fifth and sixth for (Sector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @DaveBennett's answer, you also need to pass the appropriate parameters to the procedure. Right now, you are passing an empty map, `{}`.

For example, your first call to `apoc.do.when` should be specifying `{n: n, line: line}`. Your other calls also need to be adjusted appropriately.

Comment: THANK YOU cybersam I'll give it a Try and put the feedbcak here

Comment: It works fine cyberSam . could you See please The update I've done on my Question. Many Thanks also Dave Bennett.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `line` in your `WITH` clause above.

```
...
WHERE  n.region contains "BLANKEMPTYVIDE" AND n.identifier= line.CODE_TER 
WITH n, line
...
```

and what @cybersam says too

Comment: THANK YOU Dave Bennett I've added WITH n, line but I got new error Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.util.v3_4.SyntaxException: Variable `line` not defined (line 1, column 25 (offset: 24))